# Adding additional properties to an entity framework 4 code first CTP 5 entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` and `Entity Framework code first CTP 5`.  I was wondering if it is possible to add additional properties that is not mapped to a table column?

I haved a News class and it is defined as such:

```
public class News : Entity
{
   public int NewsId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Body { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

My database context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<News> Newses { get; set; }
}
```

In the entity class I have a property defined like:

```
public IList<RuleViolation> RuleViolations { get; set; }
```

I have not code this part yet, but I want all broken rules to be added to this list when the object is validated.  The error that I am getting is:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'RuleViolation' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: The EntitySet RuleViolations is based on type RuleViolation that has no keys defined.
```

Here is my reposity code:

```
public News FindById(int newsId)
{
   return context.Database.SqlQuery<News>("News_FindById @NewsId",
      new SqlParameter("NewsId", newsId)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**UPDATE 2011-03-02:**

Here is my `Entity` class:

```
public class Entity
{
   public IList<RuleViolation> RuleViolations { get; set; }

   public bool Validate()
   {
      // Still needs to be coded
      bool isValid = true;

      return isValid;
   }
}
```

Here is my `RuleViolation` class:

```
public class RuleViolation
{
   public RuleViolation(string parameterName, string errorMessage)
   {
      ParameterName = parameterName;
      ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
   }

   public string ParameterName { get; set; }
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<News> Newses { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<News>().Ignore(n => n.RuleViolations);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can ignore the type using Fluent API by adding an ignore rule to your `OnModelCreating` method of your `MyContext` class

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {

  public DbSet<News> Newses { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {

    builder.Ignore<RuleViolation>()

  }

}
```

Or you can ignore the property by using the `NotMapped` attribute

```
public class Enitity {

  [NotMapped]
  public IList<RuleViolation> RuleViolations { get; set; }

  //other properties here

}
```

and then Entity Framework will ignore the property.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the extended answer.  Do I need to include base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);?  If so, do I then need to include your code after or before this piece of code?

Comment: @David: I'm still getting the same error.  I've updated my original post, could you please have a look.

Comment: Try `builder.Ignore<RuleViolation>();` or `builder.Entity<Entity>().Ignore(x => x.RuleViolations);` instead.

Comment: @David: I tried modelBuilder.Ignore<RuleViolation>(); and it works now.  Not sure if this is the correct way to do it?  I would prefer Ignore, but apparently it is a bug.

Comment: Your error was because Entity Framework was assuming `RuleViolation` was a complex type and trying to map it to a `RuleViolations` database table that doesn't exist. Using `modelBuilder.Ignore<RuleViolation>()` tells Entity Framework to ignore this type. It is perfectly acceptable to do it this way.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
[NotMapped]
public IList<RuleViolation> RuleViolations { get; set; }
```

To use `NotMapped` you have to add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Edit:

Now I see that you want to avoid mapping property from base class. It doesn't work with OnModelCreating - it is confirmed bug in CTP5 (I will try to find link later). I'm not sure if it works with NotMappedAttribute. This attribute is just other approach to achieve the same result.

Comment: I've decided to go with Dave's suggestion on using OnModelCreating.  Why did you suggest use NotMapped instead of OnModelCreating?  I'm still getting the error even though I did what Dave suggested.  Could you please see my updated post.

Comment: I used modelBuilder.Ignore<RuleViolation>(); and it works, but like I said I don't feel comfortable using it, I would prefer Ignore. I think for now I am going to exclude deriving from my Entity class and move the RuleViolations property to my News class, then the Ignore works perfectly. Just for now till the bug is fixed.