# Entity Framework 4 difficult query with not mapped property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, union, data-warehouse

I am a newbie in `EF` and I think that sometimes it's easier to sacrifice the advantage of ORM. But I want to know if there is a way to execute this query using `EF4`.

I have datawarehouse with fact table. Mapping looks like

```
    public class GameResult
    {
        [Key]
        public int GameResultId { get; set; } 

        public virtual Competition Competition { get; set; }    

        public virtual CustomDate DateGame { get; set; }     

        public virtual Contender ContenderFirst { get; set; }  

        public virtual Contender ContenderSecond { get; set; } 

        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

        public int ScoreContenderFirst { get; set; }

        public int ScoreContenderSecond { get; set; }

        public int PrizeStock { get; set; }

        public int Budget { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int WinCount { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int FailCount { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int DeadHeatCount { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int CountGames { get; set; } 
    }
```

And query on `sql`

```
select 
    Contenders.Name,
    sum((Case 
        when (ScoreContenderFirst > ScoreContenderSecond) then 1
        else 0
    end)) as wins,
    sum ((Case 
        when (ScoreContenderFirst = ScoreContenderSecond) then 1
        else 0
    end)) as equals,
    sum((Case 
        when (ScoreContenderFirst < ScoreContenderSecond) then 1
        else 0
    end)) as fail,
    COUNT(GameResults.GameResultId)as countGames
from GameResults 
inner join Contenders
on GameResults.ContenderSecond_ContenderId = Contenders.ContenderId
where GameResults.ContenderFirst_ContenderId = 42 
group by Contenders.Name 
UNION 
select 
    Contenders.Name,
    sum((Case 
        when (ScoreContenderFirst < ScoreContenderSecond) then 1
        else 0
    end)) as wins,
    sum ((Case 
        when (ScoreContenderFirst = ScoreContenderSecond) then 1
        else 0
    end)) as equals,
    sum((Case 
        when (ScoreContenderFirst > ScoreContenderSecond) then 1
        else 0
    end)) as fail,
    COUNT(GameResults.GameResultId)as countGames
from GameResults 
inner join Contenders
on GameResults.ContenderFirst_ContenderId = Contenders.ContenderId
where GameResults.ContenderSecond_ContenderId = 42 
group by Contenders.Name
```

This `sql` query means (I want to get game results of a particular team versus other teams (number of games that the particular team is winner, and number of games where the particular team is looser) )

Comment: Maybe you could explain what your SQL request returns, i.e. what is its goal.

Comment: Why do you store aggregated results in each individual object and not in another specific results class that's not part of the EF model?

Comment: @GertArnold I find two ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987836/creating-a-non-mapped-property-in-an-entity-entity-framework and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155853/adding-additional-properties-to-an-entity-framework-4-code-first-ctp-5-entity. ANd decide why not save aggregate results as [Not Mapped] objects. Please, offer your solution

Comment: What I'm trying to say is it doesn't make sense to store aggregated results in the objects that comprise the aggregate. You'll end up with e.g. `GameResult.WinCount`. `GameResult` has two Contenders, so who's count is it? And `GameResult` is about 1 game, what's the meaning of a count of one game? So what I mean is: the properties shouldn't be there in the first place, you need an aggregated result class. It's not a problem of how to handle unmapped properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_efContext.GameResult
          .Where(game => game.ContenderFirst_ContenderId  == 42)
          .Select(game => new { 
                    ContendersName = game.ContenderFirst.Name
                  , Win = game.ScoreContenderFirst > game.ScoreContenderSecond
                  , Draw = game.ScoreContenderFirst == game.ScoreContenderSecond
                  , Lose = game.ScoreContenderFirst < game.ScoreContenderSecond
                  })
          .GroupBy(game => game.ContendersName)
          .Select(grp => new {
                  ContendersName= grp.Key
                , Wins = grp.Where(game => game.Win).Count()
                , Draws = grp.Where(game => game.Draw).Count()
                , Loses = grp.Where(game => game.Lose).Count()
           })
```

Not include the countGames, since it is just the sum of wins, draws and loses.

For the second, you can just join with this query which looks like the first:

```
_efContext.GameResult
          .Where(game => game.ContenderSecond_ContenderId  == 42)
          .Select(game => new { 
                ContendersName = game.ContenderSecond.Name
              , Win = game.ScoreContenderFirst < game.ScoreContenderSecond
              , Draw = game.ScoreContenderFirst == game.ScoreContenderSecond
              , Lose = game.ScoreContenderFirst > game.ScoreContenderSecond
              })
          .GroupBy(game => game.ContendersName)
          .Select(grp => new {
              ContendersName= grp.Key
            , Wins = grp.Where(game => game.Win).Count()
            , Draws = grp.Where(game => game.Draw).Count()
            , Loses = grp.Where(game => game.Lose).Count()
       })
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you want me to do?

Comment: I don't understand result type of your query